# Андроид: создание разных расцветок

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, view

В общем есть программа сделанная в единой цветовой манере, все цвета описаны и грузятся из color ресурса. Но теперь мне хочется создать ещё один вариант расцветки и позволить пользователю самому выбирать её. Конечно самое простое что приходит на ум - это просто создать свой ресурс-клас, в котором по условию выбирать цвет. Но это придётся много переписывать, чтобы адаптировать программу к этому. Может есть хороший способ, например программно изменять файл ресурса цветов или разные версии файла или темы... ?

Comment: Так вроде всё понятно же. Нужно сделать для пользователя возможность изменять цвета программы в настройках. При этом сами цвета хранятся в color ресурсах. Как это сделать?

Comment: самый простой способ через if - подставлять нужную тему, по сложнее - были статьи на хабре

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению без рефакторинга не обойтись.

1. Делаем класс прослойку между ресурсами и отображением
2. Сохраняем значение выбранной темы (например в `Preference`)
3. Назначаем цвета програмно (`.setColor(MyColors.createNested(color))`)
4. Внутри `Color createNested(Color color)` имея параметры color и сохраненное значение - возвращаем необходимый цвет
5. Профит

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужны уже готовые изменяемые темы, то необходимо задать для всех изменяемых ресурсов атрибуты в файле attr.xml, затем создать тему с конкретным названием и в ней определить значение каждого из атрибутов. После в базовом классе Activity в onCreate устанавливаете нужную тему setTheme(id). Ну и в файлах layout соответственно ссылаетесь не на конкретные ресурсы, а на атрибуты.

Или же если вам просто надо чтобы пользователь мог изменять конкретные цвета, то тут для каждого цвета надо создавать запись в SharedPreferences, и при инициализации интерфейса подставлять нужные значения.